# count maximum number of edges

Tags: networking, graph, social-networking

I want to search and count for all the edges for a given (all) nodes in a big network or a graph.

What can be the algorithm to count maximum number of edges connecting to each node in a larger network?

Answer (score 0):

How is your graph represented? maximum number of connections a node can make in a network is network_size -1